# Centos 7 and netsnmp for python 3

Tags: python, centos, snmp

I installed python3 on centos 7 since I should start moving my scripts from python 2 to 3.

```
yum install python3

# rpm -qa |grep python3
python3-libs-3.6.8-13.el7.x86_64
python3-setuptools-39.2.0-10.el7.noarch
python3-pip-9.0.3-7.el7_7.noarch
python3-3.6.8-13.el7.x86_64
```

I have a script that imports netsnmp and uses it.  Works fine under python 2 but does not under python 3.

```
# rpm -qa |grep python |grep -i snmp
net-snmp-python-5.7.2-48.el7_8.1.x86_64
```

Under python3 I get this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "up.py", line 52, in <module>
    oid = netsnmp.Varbind('.1.3.6.1.2.1.1.5.0')
AttributeError: module 'netsnmp' has no attribute 'Varbind'
```

Is there a way to get netsnmp working with python 3 under centos 7 with minimal fuss and without breaking things?

Comment: I updated to describe error I get. Thanks for pointing that out.

Comment: Have you done `python3 -m pip install python3-netsnmp`? And you can do `import netsnmp`, then `print(dir(snmp))` to see what attributes/functions are availalble... But [`Varbind`](https://github.com/bluecmd/python3-netsnmp/blob/master/netsnmp/client.py#L55) does exist

Comment: >>> print(dir(netsnmp))
['__doc__', '__loader__', '__name__', '__package__', '__path__', '__spec__']

Answer (score 0):

Just run.

```
yum install python2 -y
```

Then

```
yum install python36 -y
```

It should work due to it covered or updates required dependencies.